# Links have an additional underline in gatsby

Tags: css, gatsby

I am not sure this is about CSS. In [gatsby-starter-blog](https://gatsby-starter-blog-demo.netlify.com/) links(  ) have additional underline. I mean, when you look at the source code, you will see text-decoration: none; And this works! (You can try to change it underline, line-through etc), however, there are additional lines for links and I cannot get rid of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They have a `box-shadow` prop giving the underline (That way it's spaced a little wider and gives a nicer look instead of a tight underline):

```
a {
  /* This first prop */
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 currentColor;
  color: #007acc;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

so just cancel it out with your custom css:

```
a {
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's use `box-shadow` property on anchor tag for bottom border. Change `box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 currentColor;` to `box-shadow: none;` will resolve your issue. Thanks

```
a {
    box-shadow: none;
    color: #007acc;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```